# How to add right click menu item to create a launcher in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

When I create desktop icon launchers I need to use an extensive workaround.

Using "dconf editor" is a workaround to enable launchers on desktop.
IN dconf editor go to org > desktop > background
then enable "show desktop icons" option.

Then create an empty file and name it, but with .desktop as an extension.

Example: `gedit.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=gedit
Exec=/usr/bin/gedit
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/accessories-text-editor.png
```

Then save and right-click on the launcher to allow execution.

That is currently how I make launchers.

---

But is there a simpler way to make a launcher...

Is there a way to make a right click menu item that will create or add a launcher to the desktop?

Comment: This is not Canonical Support, it is a forum for Ubuntu users.  Complaining to us is worse than useless, since it makes people think something useful has been done when Canonical pays no attention to stuff here.

Comment: Plenty of Canonical folks answering questions here, either way this question has nothing to do with Canonical and feature requests are offtopic here anyway.